# PostgreQL fetch data from Json field which of type multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql

I was finding the query that fetch the data from table of column which of json type.

My table looks like:

```
`ID | ParentID |        Details`

`-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`1  |  10      | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_draft": "false"}, "default_locale": "en"}}`

`2  |  20      | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_draft": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}`

`3  |  30      | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_draft": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}`

`4  |  40      | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_draft": "false"}, "default_locale": "en"}}`
```

I want to fetch those row whose `is_draft = false`.

Please someone can help me this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that we don't even know which keys would have child JSON objects with `is_draft` set to `false`, one option here would be to just cast the JSON to text and search it using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Details::text LIKE '%"is_draft": "false"%';
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
   id,
   parent_id, 
   details
FROM books
WHERE details->'_translated' -> 'en_US' -> 'is_draft' ='false' 
OR details->'_translated' -> 'en_CA' -> 'is_draft' ='false' ;
```